# MySQL - Convert coded values based on Key/Value Lookup Table

Tags: mysql, sql, lookup-tables

I have 2 MySQL tables. One contains form entries and another contains key/values pairs to lookup.

Their structure is as follows :

```
Table 1 : form_123

id | element_6 | element_7 | element_8 | element_9
1       1          6             3           6
2       4          7             2           4
3       3          3             5           2


Table 2 : Options

id   |  formid   |   option_id    |  option_name
1        123             1            sausages
2        123             2            bananas
3        123             3            grapes
4        123             4            fish
5        123             5            bread
6        123             6            buckfast
7        123             7            foo
8        123             8            bar
9        123             9            apples
10       123            10            oranges
```

What is the most elegant MySQL query to provide the following output. The intention is convert the key/value lookup codes in table form_123 to the lookup values via a single select statement if possible.

```
id | element_6 | element_7 | element_8 | element_9
1   sausages      buckfast     grapes    buckfast
2       fish       foo         bananas   fish
3       grapes     grapes      bread     bananas
```

Comment: Edited to correct expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use INNER JOIN(s) like this

```
SELECT f.id,
       o6.option_name as element_6,
       o7.option_name as element_7,
       o8.option_name as element_8,
       o9.option_name as element_9
FROM form_123 f
INNER JOIN options o6 ON f.element_6 = o6.option_id
INNER JOIN options o7 ON f.element_7 = o7.option_id
INNER JOIN options o8 ON f.element_8 = o8.option_id
INNER JOIN options o9 ON f.element_9 = o9.option_id
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9656d/2)
your sample desired output seems off btw.

output

```
id  element_6       element_7       element_8       element_9
1   sausages        buckfast        grapes          buckfast
2   fish            foo             bananas         fish
3   grapes          grapes          bread           bananas
```

if you have more formid(s) coming you can add the WHERE all formids are 123
like this

```
SELECT f.id,
       o6.option_name as element_6,
       o7.option_name as element_7,
       o8.option_name as element_8,
       o9.option_name as element_9
FROM form_123 f
INNER JOIN options o6 ON f.element_6 = o6.option_id 
INNER JOIN options o7 ON f.element_7 = o7.option_id 
INNER JOIN options o8 ON f.element_8 = o8.option_id 
INNER JOIN options o9 ON f.element_9 = o9.option_id 
WHERE o6.formid = 123
  AND o7.formid = 123
  AND o8.formid = 123
  AND o9.formid = 123
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```

or you can just add the AND formid = 123 condition on the ON condition like this

```
SELECT f.id,
       o6.option_name as element_6,
       o7.option_name as element_7,
       o8.option_name as element_8,
       o9.option_name as element_9
FROM form_123 f
INNER JOIN options o6 ON f.element_6 = o6.option_id AND o6.formid = 123
INNER JOIN options o7 ON f.element_7 = o7.option_id AND o7.formid = 123
INNER JOIN options o8 ON f.element_8 = o8.option_id AND o8.formid = 123
INNER JOIN options o9 ON f.element_9 = o9.option_id AND o9.formid = 123
ORDER BY f.id ASC
```